# No Oracle DataSource in Entity Data Model Wizard

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework, orm, odp.net

I am using ODP.NET and I need generate ORM from my database.

I have installed:

- Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate
- ODAC1120250Beta_EntityFramework_x64.zip

In Server Expolorer I can see Data Source for Oracle Database and I am able connect to remote oracle server and run queries.

When I add ADO.NET Entity Data Model and wanna generate code from database I cannot see Data source for oracle like in Server Explorer.

Do you need download some extra stuff to run entity framework with ODP.NET?

**EDIT:**

1. Use latest version of ODP.NET
2. Uncheck Oracle services for Microsoft Transaction Server .... During the installation

Answer (score 2):

You must install ODAC 11.2.0.2.30 or higher, **32-bit** version.
Entity Framework was not supported in earlier versions and it is not currently supported in 64-bit ODAC.
see:
   https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2202085

i do this (i had  vs 2010 pro SP1 on W764), and use "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" for good work in LINK request.

"Classe LINK to SQL" dont work.

Comment: This does NOT answer the OP's question. BTW, I have the same problem, and I have 32 but version installed

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by unintall the ODP.NET and reinstall back. During the installing process, the ODP.NET will detect visual studio and be sure the CHECK the option. After that, the oracle managed driver appear in Data Provider.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

What ultimately worked in my case (VS2017):

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Uninstall ODT and ODAC non-compliant (older) versions. In my case the entire ODTwithODAC121021,
3. Install newest version, in my case ODTwithODAC122010.
4. Start VS again.

In fact, I uninstalled everything Oracle-related but SQL Developer.
Then installed ODTwithODAC122010 and Entity Data Model for Oracle connections showed up right after. Microsoft Transaction Server option not unchecked, no issues found.

ODTwithODAC122010 taken from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html