# Why Oracle does not show as a drop down option in Entity Data Model Wizard but does in Server Explorer?

Tags: odp.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

Oracle does not appear as a Data Source drop down list option.[image]

This has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818966/no-oracle-datasource-in-entity-data-model-wizard), but the answer there does not solve my problem (and for others as well, as per comments there).

What's interesting is that in **trying to add a Data Connection via VS Server Explorer window, Oracle does appear as a Data Source option.**

[image]

Trying to install the data provider (via install_odpm.bat) for a different platform (x86, x64) had no effect.

Also have tried installing both Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess nuget packages.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to install oracle client adapter:
Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio.
You can download the adapter from here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html

Also, you can see more information about oracle database in visual studio here: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/buildingnetapplications/BuildingNETApplications.htm

Comment: Thanks Matan. Problem is that this installation requires installing oracle client altogether. I wanted to avoid that, since this is already installed. All I need is the Developer Tools, I guess. But I can't find in the internet an option for downloading and installing developer tools only. If I have no alternative... will have to uninstall and install the whole pack (client + developer tools).

Comment: Veverke, if you check the download page tomorrow you should see a new MSI install in which Oracle Developer Tools is fully managed (no dependency on Oracle client). It is due to be published for the first time tomorrow.